# How to open android app if someone visits our website?

Tags: javascript, android, wordpress

I've a website for which I've created a webview application for android device. What i want to do is if someone visits my website from android devices i want to prompt a message that says open in app. If user has the app already installed. When the user click on the button it open up the android app with the same url.

Answer (score 1):

Your app needs to handle a custom URI scheme under the "intent-filter"

```
<intent-filter>
  <data android:scheme="your_uri_scheme" />
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
</intent-filter>
```

And your Android app needs to verify the URI was opened successfully

```
Uri data = this.getIntent().getData();
if (data != null && data.isHierarchical()) {
  String uri = this.getIntent().getDataString();
  Log.i("MyApp", "Deep link clicked " + uri);
}
```

Then the page can call the app within Android if such a URI is registered with the OS

```
var fallbackToStore = function() {
  window.location.replace('market://details?id=com.myapp.package');
};
var openApp = function() {
  window.location.replace('your_uri_scheme://');
};
var triggerAppOpen = function() {
  openApp();
  setTimeout(fallbackToStore, 250);
};
```

This is all taken from https://blog.branch.io/how-to-open-an-android-app-from-the-browser/ all credits to them.